# Make the page number Lower in TOC

Tags: margins

I am writing my master thesis on latex and I had a problem because the University wants specific margin (top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,left=3cm,bottom=2.5cm) and also when any chapter starts the top margin must change to be (top=5cm) my problem is that the latex thinks that TOC, list of figures, list of tables and Bibliography chapters and I want the top margin of each of them to be (top=2.5cm) not (top=5cm) I have solved all the top margin to each of them except TOC I used the command

\addtocontents{toc}{\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1.3in}}

to make the top=2.5cm but also the page number want upper like in the picture [image]

if there is another way to make the top margin change please help me solve this problem I have to deliver the thesis this week ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be helpful here since we have no idea how your layout is currently defined. Without an MWE, any code we suggest is likely to create other problems even if it solves this one, which isn't terribly likely.

Comment: Please indicate which document class you use as well as which packages you load to affect (a) the page layout and (b) the formatting of document units such as the TOC, LOF, and LOT.

Comment: I am using \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report} and about (a) usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfprintscaling=None}

Comment: I am using \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report} and about (a) usepackage{hyperref}\hypersetup{pdfprintscaling=None}

Comment: (b)TOC (\iffront@pages\tableofcontents\else\addtocounter{page}{1})

Comment: LOF(\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
        \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\vspace{-3.2cm}\begin{center} \hspace{2.5cm}{\Large LIST OF FIGURES}\newline{\large \; \; { Figure}\hspace{4cm} { Descraption} \hfill Page}\end{center}}
         \listoffigures)

Comment: and LOT(\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
        \renewcommand{\listtablename}{\vspace{-3.2cm}\begin{center} \hspace{2.5cm}{\Large LIST OF TABLES}\newline{\large \; \; { Table} \hspace{4cm} { Descraption} \hfill Page}\end{center}}\listoftables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for answering my question but I found what I want. I have used this command and it worked perfectly:

**

```
\begingroup
\makeatletter
% Redefine the \chapter* header macro to remove vertical space
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}% Remove the vertical space
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
\iffront@pages\tableofcontents\else\addtocounter{page}{1}\fi
    \newpage
\endgroup
```

**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `titlesec` package to redefine the formatting and spacing of chapters, and choose different settings for the vertical spacings of numbered and unnumbered chapters.